# Could not load the assembly 'Version=1.0.0.0,Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=24e9d7d011937483'. Make sure that it is compiled before accessing the page

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, web

A bit of a back story - I am trying to create a custom dispform page for my list in VS2010. I used instructions found [here to do it][1]. I successfully created the custom form and had the site loading it instead of the default, but am now getting stuck while adding a code behind page. I am 99% sure the issue is with my namespace and inheritance on the asp page, but I can't for the life of me figure out the issue. I was hoping someone out her can. Here's my code:

```
<%@ Page language="C#" CodeBehind="DispRequest.aspx.cs" MasterPageFile="~masterurl/default.master" Inherits="Solvera.SellIT.DispRequest.Solvera.SellIT,Version=1.0.0.0,Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=24e9d7d011937483"  %>
<%@ Register Tagprefix="SharePoint" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<%@ Register Tagprefix="Utilities" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint" %>
<%@ Assembly Name="$SharePoint.Project.AssemblyFullName$" %>
<%@ Assembly Name="Microsoft.Web.CommandUI, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<%@ Register Tagprefix="WebPartPages" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
```

And from the code behind file which is named disprequest.aspx.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages;


namespace Solvera.SellIT
{
class DispRequest:WebPartPage
{
    protected Button btnSubmitOffer;
    protected TextBox txtOfferAmount;
```

I would greatly appreciate any help anyone can provide.

Thank you,

Comment: Should Solvera.SellIT.DispRequest.Solvera.SellIT just be Solvera.SellIT.DispRequest ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I have resolved this issue with the help of another user at sharepoint.stackexchange.  I had two things going against me.  Somewhere along the way I had mixed up my namespace and class between my aspx and code-behind.  I also put in the wrong public token (I copied it from another the page I was using to help with the process I was trying to create).

Once I corrected these two issues, I no longer had the issues I listed here.

Thanks to everyone for their input.

Answer (score 0):

Replace this

```
<%@ Page language="C#" CodeBehind="DispRequest.aspx.cs" MasterPageFile="~masterurl/default.master" Inherits="Solvera.SellIT.DispRequest.Solvera.SellIT,Version=1.0.0.0,Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=24e9d7d011937483"  %>
```

with

```
<%@ Page language="C#" CodeBehind="DispRequest.aspx.cs" MasterPageFile="~masterurl/default.master" Inherits="Solvera.SellIT.DispRequest"%>
```

Comment: After trying your suggestion I receive Could not load type 'Solvera.SellIT.DisRequest"

Comment: Perhaps I also missed an important piece of information.  My DispForm.aspx page exists in a Module called Forms.  Does this affect my inheritence?